# How to sort documents in MongoDB based on keys inside a dictionary in document using MongoEngine Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

So I have documents of this type in my MongoDB Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606c66c875a2fe6153bfc71f"),
    "t_id" : "12345678a",
    "r_id" : "r12345678a",
    "t_e_stats" : {
        "acc" : "70"
    },
    "register_time" : ISODate("2021-04-06T19:18:56.890Z")
}
```

There are multiple of these documents with same 't_id' and different 't_e_stats' dictionary. But all 't_e_stats' dictionary have 'acc' key in them. Now I want to query the entry for a particular 't_id' with the maximum value of 'acc' in the 't_e_stats' dictionary. How do I do that in MongoEngine? Or I have found there are ways to run PyMongo queries in MongoEngine also, how to use that too if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by OP

```
Model.objects(t_id="12345678a").order_by("-t_e_stats.acc").first()
```

if anyone is interested in not only the object but also the JSON document, then you can do this:

```
[data_entry._data for data_entry in Model.objects(t_id="12345678a").order_by("-t_e_stats.acc")][0]
```

---

Use [.sort](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=sort#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort)

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find%20one#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one

```
mycol.find_one({ "t_id" : "12345678a" }).sort("t_e_stats.acc", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

This will return 1st record where `t_e_stats.acc` is max.

---

mongo shell

```
db.collection.find({ "t_id" : "12345678a" }).sort("t_e_stats.acc", -1).limit(1);
```

---

Mongoengine

```
Model.objects.get(t_id="12345678a").order_by("-t_e_stats.acc").first()
```

Comment: But this answer is for native PyMongo. I am looking for solution in MongoEngine.

Comment: @raghavsikaria what do you mean by MongoEngine ?

Comment: It's another high level abstracted library for connecting and querying to MongoDB via Python.

Comment: Thank you. Small correction: we don't need 'get' here. It works without it. Like: `Model.objects(t_id="12345678a").order_by("-t_e_stats.acc").first()` and also, just for reference to another reader in future, if anyone is interested in not only the object but also the JSON document, then you can do this: `[data_entry._data for data_entry in Model.objects(t_id="12345678a").order_by("-t_e_stats.acc")][0]`

Comment: @raghavsikaria Glad, it helped also updated the answer with the details you mentioned, feel free to edit the answer if you want to add details,